# How to calculate coordinates to keep element in the user screen's region

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add an absolute element on coordinates `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` where `e` is the `event` object passed to the `mouseover` callback function.

It's not a problem:

```
element.css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'z-index': 300,
    'left': e.pageX,
    'top': e.pageY
  });
```

The problem is that the new element can be placed outside of the current user's screen so they needs to scroll the page to view the corresponding element.

How can I check for boundaries and do the appropriate calculations to make it appear in the user screen's region?

Do you know any ready-made solution or should I think about custom one by myself?

Comment: Did you try `position: fixed` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var left = e.pageX;
var top = e.pageY;
var right = $( window ).width();
var bottom = $( window ).height();
var elwidth = element.offsetWidth;    /* assuming "element" is an element reference */
var elheight = element.offsetHeight;  /* assuming "element" is an element reference */

if ((e.pageX + elwidth) > right) {
   left = e.pageX - ((e.pageX + elwidth) - right);
}
if ((e.pageY + elheight) > bottom) {
   top = e.pageY - ((e.pageY + elheight) - bottom);
}

element.css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'z-index': 300,
  'left': left,
  'top': top
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work -- page still expanding horizontally

Comment: @FrozenHeart Did you test the values so they makes sense? ... btw, what are the values ? ... and did you replace the `element.height` with the real number?, as you can't use `element.height` as is